Should I call the company about my application if something urgent has come up?
I have to vacate my current apartment before this coming June 24. I had been set on moving to another place until I received in the first week of this month an email inviting me to a job interview at a company I thought had rejected my application. I gave an interview in the same week, and I was told by the company's HR officer to wait within the next twenty days or until June 26 for an update. My problem is that if I don’t get an update before this week ends, I’ll have to move to this new place that’s far away from where the company is. If, on the other hand, I get an update before Friday, I can probably look for temporary accommodation near the company while I look for a permanent apartment.
I sent the company a generic follow-up email last Friday, but it hasn’t responded yet. Is it appropriate, then, to call the company/HR officer today or tomorrow? If so, should I also tell the company/HR officer about my situation?

Why would you not? However, you should probably plan on using a mover who can just put everything into storage while your final destination is uncertain...This is one of the things containerized moving ix good for; they can just warehouse the entire container until you are ready to unpack it.

@keshlam Thanks for the advice!

@keshlam shouldn't that be an answer?

@RohitGupta: Barely. It's mostly a side suggestion on a possible way to manage one if the sub-issues mentioned. And there are good answers; another isn't needed.

Yes, you absolutely should call them and up and let them know your situation.
When job hunting, companies understand that sometimes circumstances change and that sometimes there are critical decisions that are dependent on whether or not you get that particular role or not.
I have done this several times - in various guises:
Situation 1: There was a job that I wasnt super keen on (was a sunset industry), but they were offering a good chunk more money than the other offers I had. I had received a written offer from another 2 companies and indicated I would give answers at the end of the business week. I called up this industry (as I had an interview scheduled for the next week) and asked if they could move the interview forward as I had written offers - they declined, I said thank you very much - and accepted one of the offers.
Situation 2: I had pretty much accepted an Offer from Company 1, but I had another company that were quite keen on me. I let them know that I was in the late stages with Company 1 and was likely to accept - they then rushed forward the process to try and win me, but ultimately it was too-little, too-late from them (they only offered an extra $4K per annum and they sent the email through an hour after I had told them they needed to send it).
So yes, if you have critical decisions that are dependent on whether you get an offer - you can absolutely raise it with them.
If you are the preferred candidate (or one of the preferred candidates) - the company will expedite the process for you.
If you are not one of the preferred candidates, they won't - and you will know not to waste your time.
